# Integers to const c++, c

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have integers which I put in a matrix in order to use them in a specific function in openCV. The matrix that I created is only cvMat and I want to use this matrix in the function. I'm getting an error:

> error: cannot convert ‘CvMat’ to ‘const CvMat*’

So how can I convert these ints to const in order to create that matrix as const CvMat i.e how to change CvMat to const CvMat?

Comment: You are passing by value where you should be passing a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> " error: cannot convert ‘CvMat’ to ‘const CvMat*’ "

The important thing there is the asterix at the end.  That means the function you are calling wants a pointer.  you can just take the address of your matrix and pass that, instead `somefunction(myMatrix)` it needs `somefunction(&myMatrix)`.  Don't worry about the const.  A pointer can always be converted to a const pointer implicitly.

Comment: You're very welcome. If this helped you please consider accepting my answer.  you might also want to get that caps lock key checked out.

Comment: You really should accept his answer click the big checkbox by his answer.